# How to add segments to HKWorkout so it shows in FItness app

Tags: swift, healthkit

[image]

I want to add segments into running HKWorkout.
As i understand i should use `addWorkoutEvents` method on my HKWorkoutBuilder.
So my code is

```
func saveSegment(forStep step: GymWorkoutEventStep) {
    let dateInterval = DateInterval(start: step.startDate ?? Date(), end: Date())
    let metadata = [
        HKMetadataKeyWasUserEntered: true
    ]
    let event = HKWorkoutEvent(type: .segment, dateInterval: dateInterval, metadata: metadata)
    builder?.addWorkoutEvents([event], completion: { success, error in
        print(success ? "Success saving segment" : error.debugDescription)
    })
}
```

I'm trying to implement same feature like in Apple Watch app "Workout" when we can switch to next segment on double tap.
So my code works, i can see in console "Success saving segment". But then, when i'm finishin workout, Fitness app doesn't show Segments section at all.
What i'm missing? And how to add distance, pace to each segment, because i can't see any MetadataKey's for it?

Comment: How did you test this? Maybe the segments were too short, and therefore the Fitness app (correctly) assumes the data is unrealistic, and doesn’t display it. This is always a risk when testing the app “in the lab”.

Answer (score 1):

If someone else is struggling with this: The segments in the Fitness app view are generated based on `HKWorkoutEventType.marker` events within the `workoutEvents` array. Also, Apple's documentation is here a bit misleading from my point of view.